# Godot 4.1 keeps crashing on starting up editor with this error message

Tags: crash, gdscript, godot4

I am coding a project in Godot 4.1, and I get tired so I close the editor.

I come back the next day, and after opening the editor, this error pops up:

**`Blend file import is enabled in the project settings, but no Blender path is configured in the editor settings. Blend files will not be imported.`**

As soon as i open the editor, I get a quick glimpse of this message, and then Godot crashes.

**I am coding a 2D platformer in Godot 4.1**

**I need a way to fix the problem without opening the editor, because I cannot do anything in the editor**

Answer (score 0):

Not having Blender configured is not a reason for Godot to crash. Instead, what is likely is that the real cause of the crash never gets to output an error message.

---

**Look at the errors in the terminal**

You will have a better chance at getting the error message if you launch Godot from the terminal/console. As in, open the terminal/console and launch Godot from it. *You should be able to find how to do this for your operating system version with a web search.*

Godot will push to the terminal/console everything that goes to the output panel. So you will see errors and other messages there. The point of opening Godot from the terminal/console is so you can see the errors after Godot crashed.

---

**Locate the logs in the data folders**

You could also find the logs. Unless you have configured a different location for them, they should be in the data folder of the project.

So, you need to find out where Godot stores logs in your operating system. That is covered in the documentation: [Accessing persistent user data](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html#accessing-persistent-user-data-user).

Alternatively you can get it from the editor, but for that you need a project that opens for that. So open or create another project, and go to Project -> Open User Data Folder. That will open the folder where Godot stores logs and other data for that project, the folders for the other projects should be in the same location.

---

**Getting rid of the Blender path error**

Let us fix the .blend file issue too. You either:

- Remove any .blend files in your project. These should be Blender files, being Blender a 3D editor, and you working in 2D, you probably don't need them... If you are using the .blend files for something else, don't. That will just lead to trouble with Godot.
- Or configure the path where you have Blender installed (If you don't have it, then download it and install it). Again for that you need to access the editor, so open or create another project. You set the path in Editor -> Editor Settings -> General -> FileSystem -> Import -> Blender 3 Path. *No, Blender 4 is not supported at the time of writing.*

---

**Narrowing down what triggers the crash**

Your goal should be to discard what is and what isn't the source of the problem.

If you have version control. **You should use version control o,.,o.** You can revert to old commits and try opening the project to see if they also crash. You are looking for the first commit that crashes, as it would have been the one that introduced the problem.

You might also want to removing the .godot folder (which I assume you would not be tracking in your repository) so Godot regenerates it.

If you don't have version control. **Good luck o,.,o.** You could try creating a new project and start moving things from the old one until the new one fails. *You could also try removing things from the old one until it works.*

Regardless, it remains good advice to make a copy of the project (including files not tracked in the repository, if you have one), just to be safe.

---

If you manage to isolate the cause of the problem, please open a bug report at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues - It would also be helpful if you can check if other versions of Godot (e.g. Godot 4.0, Godot 4.2) are also affected.

*Even if you don't manage to isolate the problem, a crash is a crash, and it is better not let it unreported. But be aware that often Godot developers often have their hands full... So it is likely that you will be able to workaround the problem and continue with your project before they have a patch ready. Don't be Waiting on Godot.*

Answer (score 0):

Almost all setting files are text-based, meaning you can edit them in a text editor.

Start from "your_project.godot" file, open in text editor, move at the end of the file, add the following two lines, and try again.

```
[filesystem]

import/blender/enabled=false
```

If you can open your project by doing this, help us with a little experimenting:

- open the file again, and find the line you added, change `false` to `true`, and try opening the project again.

  - the setting is new in version 4.1, and comes enabled by default, but path to blender is empty.
- if the same crash happens again, let us know with a comment.

Edit: this should not be, but just in case, check if the same line is already there and set to `true`. If so, make it to `false`.